# how to pass java variable value into sql statement entry in log4j.properties file

Tags: logging, log4j

I am using a JDBC appender in which I wrote a sql query
which logs into the table with table structure as shown

```
Column name  Null  Type
------------ ----- -----------------
DATED              DATE
LEVEL1             VARCHAR2(10)
MESSAGE            VARCHAR2(1000)
TIME               TIMESTAMP(5)
LOGGER             VARCHAR2(25)
MODULE             VARCHAR2(75)
USER1              VARCHAR2(35)
OBJ_ID             VARCHAR2(25)
```

and the entry in my log4j.properties file for the query is

`log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES('%d{dd-MMM-yy}','%p','%m','%d{dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss}','%C','%t','username','obid')`

I want the `USER` and `OBJ_ID` column values to be passed through a java file into log4j.properties.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the log4j MDC as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554172/logging-username-in-log4j) or [here](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/). This basically gives you a variable `%X{user1}` and so on in *log4j.properties*.